# PHP strcmp() is giving me number '6' as output

Tags: php, regex, strcmp

I am comparing two short strings (some containing numbers, some containing letters, some are mixed) with strcmp() expecting output would be 0, -1 or 1 (or I will say it differently: there definitely has to be 1 match but it is always 'no match', that is always not 0) but for some strange reason I am getting '6' no matter what, this is my code:

```
$_delim = '</div>';
$_str = '';
$_struct = explode($_delim, file_get_contents($_pthPHP.'_sets.php'));
$_c = count($_struct);
$_patternIMG = '/data-img="(.*?)"/';
$_patternLIKTYPE = '/data-link-type="(.*?)"/';

for ($i = 0; $i < ($_c - 1); $i++)
{
    preg_match($_patternIMG, $_struct[$i], $matchesA); // DATA-IMG = NAZOV SETU
    $_iteratedSet = explode('<?= $def_path ?>', $matchesA[1]);
    $_actualSet = explode('-', $verzia);

    $_strA = trim($_iteratedSet[1]);
    $_strB = trim($_actualSet[0]);

    echo strcmp((string)$_strA, (string)$_strB).'<br />'; // TESTING COMPARISON VALUE

    if(strcmp($_strA, $_strB) == 0)
    {
        preg_match($_patternLIKTYPE, $_struct[$i], $matchesB); // DATA-LINK-TYPE
        $_linkType = $matchesB[1];
        echo 'link type = '.$_linkType;
        break;
    }
}
```

I was looking for a solution and I found here on StackOverflow one supposed solution which basically adds file prefix of '(string)' to both compared strings but it has no effect whatsoever and the output is still that strange '6' - anyone know why and can help me, please?

**SOLVED**

2 things happened:
- I mistakenly thought output can be only 0, 1 or -1
- I mistakenly entered wrong variable to one of the strings :-(

...so now all is as expected, thanx to @Erhan for the explanation (the code above is already fixed so it actually show the functional one)

Comment: *"with `strcmp()` expecting output would be 0, -1 or 1"* -- why do you expect these return values? Have you read the [documentation of `strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)? Read it (again) and insist on the ["Return Values"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#refsect1-function.strcmp-returnvalues) section.

Comment: @axiac you are right, I was wrong...see my updated post please, my fault (I understood it wrongly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output does not exactly has to be 1 or -1. If they are equal output will be zero (0) if not output will be <0 or >0
from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

> Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than
>   str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking - after reading reading W3Schools example for strcmp() - that the output should always be 0, -1 or 1, my bad: your answer i actually the right answer, thank you

Comment: @errerr can you post the link to the page on W3Schools where this thing is stated?

Comment: yes, I can tho it is more like I UNDERSTOOD IT WRONGLY what is being written there as english is not my native language as I opened those examples they have there ans I saw only 0, -1 or +1, my fault, sorrry